# PHP variable in a string

Tags: php

I have this tiny code:

```
$a = "apple";
$var = "I like the $a";
echo $var;
echo "<br>";
$a = "pear";
echo $var;

OUTPUT:
I like the apple
I like the apple

OUTPUT I NEED:
I like the apple
I like the pear
```

Anyone knows how can I update the var in the string dynamically?
Thanks

Comment: create function `function echoWhatILike($fruit) { echo 'I like the '.$fruit; }`

Comment: Since you are using double quotes  the variable will be substituted without more ado - see the string documentation in the php manual http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single (halfway down the page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `$var` string is parsed at the moment the interpreter reaches it, so changing your  `$a` variable won't replace its value. There are many options to accomplish what you are trying to do alternatively.

You can store your string format in `$var` and then apply `sprintf`:

```
$var = 'I like the %s';
echo sprintf($var, 'apple');
echo sprintf($var, 'pear');
```

Or you could just create a function that receives what you like as a parameter:

```
function generateLikeString($what) {
    return "I like the $what";
}

echo generateLikeString('apple');
echo generateLikeString('pear');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the value of `$a` after you have used it in `$var`. It will not affect `$var` if you change `$a` afterwards. You have to do this again:

```
$a = "pear";
$var = "I like the $a";
```

Or do this:

```
$a = "apple";
$var = "I like the ";
echo $var . $a;
echo "<br>";
$a = "pear";
echo $var . $a;
```